# Copy a file to a folder which requires admin permissions in powershell

Tags: powershell

I want to copy a hosts file to `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc` via a powershell script but when I do, I get the below error. How can I run this command as admin without displaying the password?

Error I receive:

```
copy : Access to the path 'C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts' is denied.
At line:1 char:1
+ copy z:\hosts C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (Z:\hosts:FileInfo) [Copy-Item], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CopyFileInfoItemUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
```

Command I run:

```
copy z:\hosts C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have administrator permissions, then you start PowerShell as administrator, or you can run the script as an administrator by adding,

`Start-Process powershell -Verb runAs`

Answer (score 0):

From a PowerShell Session of a normal user (not -runAs), I use usually a single line copy like this, as I'm logged in as admin on my computer:

```
Start-Process PowerShell -Verb runAs -ArgumentList '-command Copy-Item -force z:\hosts C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc'
```

Windows popups a confirmation, I then click on yes. If you want to avoid totally the popup Winddows, we must lower the system security level:

Search Bar\UAC\User Acount Control Parameters\Lower the slide at the lowest level.

This is a bad solution.

[image]

Comment: i need it to run without any prompts

Comment: Sorry, I found no other way to disable Windows Security popup that is linked to Windows Software Certificate control, than lowering the Windows Security Settings. - a very bad thing. I restored the level after testing.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I used, is;

First I added a Self-Elevate to the script so that if it requires Administrator permissions, it will prompt the UAC(Corporate domain).

```
    # Self-elevate the script if required
if (-Not ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal] [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] 'Administrator')) {
 if ([int](Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_OperatingSystem | Select-Object -ExpandProperty BuildNumber) -ge 6000) {
  $CommandLine = "-File `"" + $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path + "`" " + $MyInvocation.UnboundArguments
  Start-Process -FilePath PowerShell.exe -Verb Runas -ArgumentList $CommandLine
  Exit
 }
}
```

This will evaluate the commands you are running and open a new PowerShell Window in Administrator mode.

Here is where I found an example;

https://blog.expta.com/2017/03/how-to-self-elevate-powershell-script.html